simplify a comparison macro
I know there is an internal comparison function \fp_compare:nTF in expl3. I also found a similar function from On the xfp package: Comparison . how to simplify \xifthenelse{\fptest{\x<\y}}{TRUE}{FALSE} to
\fptest{\x>\y}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be F) ?
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_eq:NN \fptest \fp_compare_p:n

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \xxifthen_legacy_conditional:n { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \use:c { if#1 } \prg_return_true: \else: \prg_return_false: \fi:
 }
\cs_new_eq:NN \boolean \xxifthen_legacy_conditional_p:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\x{6.25}
\def\y{-2}

\xifthenelse{\fptest{\x<\y}}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be F)

%\fptest{\x<\y}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be F)

\end{document}


@DavidCarlisle edited already.

The \xifthenelse has, by design, a syntax similar to the legacy \ifthenelse. If you look at the code, \fptest is just
\fp_compare_p:n

so you can simply do
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\FPcompare}{mmm}{\fp_compare:nTF {#1}{#2}{#3}}

Similarly for all other tests. I believe that \fptest may be a good name in the context of \xifthenelse, but not a good name for an independent conditional.

I would just use \fp_compare:nNnTF but with a latex2e-name:
\documentclass{article}


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifthenelse}{mmm}
 {
  \bool_if:nTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\fptest{m}{ \fp_compare_p:nNn#1}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\def\x{6.25}
\def\y{-2}

\xifthenelse{\fptest{\x<\y}}{TRUE}{FALSE} (should be FALSE)

But why the indirection through \verb |\xifthenelse{\fptest| ??

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\fptestb{}{ \fp_compare:nNnTF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fptestb \x<\y {TRUE}{FALSE} (should be FALSE)


or


\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\fptestc{}{ \fp_compare:nTF}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\fptestc {\x<\y} {TRUE}{FALSE} (should be FALSE)

\end{document}

Note xparse and xfp are not needed in current latex.

the reason why the indirection through \verb |\xifthenelse{\fptest| ?? is that there were many kinds of comparison in original linked code.

Any particular reason why you're using \fp_compare:nNnTF instead of \fp_compare:nTF (which would have the syntax shown in OP)?

@Skillmon er possibly not, I could show both I guess. thanks

in accordance with \x<\y {TRUE}{FALSE} ,  nNnTF is requried

@Skillmon see \fptestc I just added

@xcn the syntax you show in your question is \fptest{\x<\y}{TRUE}{FALSE}.

thanks. I should focus on my question.
